# How to group by the last date in a month in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a `df`

```
qty         val         date
10          100         2021-09-15
11          111         2021-09-22
20          222         2021-09-22
35          333         2021-09-15
45          444         2021-10-15
79          555         2021-10-15
79          555         2021-10-07
87          666         2021-11-15
45          777         2021-11-15
97          888         2021-11-22
```

I am trying to group the values by the `max(date)` of each month, so I would only take the values of `2021-09-22 / 2021-10-15 / 2021-11-22` because these dates are the highest of each month. I would expect to get the sum of `qty & val` for those dates during `groupby`. Or just group by `date` and then select only the values of the last date of `date`, but I assume that removing unwanted data first is more efficient.

I tried using:

```
group = df.groupby('date')
group_max = groups.apply(lambda g: g[g['date'] == g['date'].max()])
```

But with no luck, how would I filter before or after grouping so that I would only get the values of the last dates of each month in a `date`?

Comment: what type is the date column? string or timedate?

Comment: It is datetime, beforehand I use `df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pandas.Grouper`:

```
# pre-requisite
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

g = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M', key='date'))
df[df['date'].eq(g['date'].transform('max'))]
```

output:

```
   qty  val       date
1   11  111 2021-09-22
2   20  222 2021-09-22
4   45  444 2021-10-15
5   79  555 2021-10-15
9   97  888 2021-11-22
```